# Is there a linq to entities equivalent for the LAG() function in SQL?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I created a query for a Month-Over-Month Sales report using the LAG function in SQL. I discovered that is not available in linq. Is there a way to still accomplish this?

Comment: The only way is to send the raw SQL query using `LAG()` to the server (or call a SP containing it), then process the results.

Comment: You could use a self-join, or if you are filtering your query sufficiently before querying, or if your tables are sufficiently small, you could bring over the entire table and use LINQ to Objects to handle the query on the client side.

Answer (score 2):

[`LinqTo2Db`](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db) supports [Window-Functions](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db/wiki/Window-Functions-(Analytic-Functions)) `Lag` and `Lead`:

```cs
from x in db.Events
let prev = Sql.Ext
                .Lag(x.app, Sql.Nulls.None)
                .Over()
                .OrderBy(x.time)
                .ToValue()
where  (prev != x.app && prev != null)
select (prev, x.app)
```

---

First `8` of all [**43** supported funcs](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db/wiki/Window-Functions-(Analytic-Functions)#functions-mapping) (!)

```
|-------------|----------------------| 
|    SQL      |       Linq2db        |
|-------------|----------------------| 
| AVG         | Sql.Ext.Average()    |
| CORR        | Sql.Ext.Corr()       |
| COUNT       | Sql.Ext.Count()      |
| COVAR_POP   | Sql.Ext.CovarPop()   |
| COVAR_SAMP  | Sql.Ext.CovarSamp()  |
| CUME_DIST   | Sql.Ext.CumeDist()   |
| DENSE_RANK  | Sql.Ext.DenseRank()  |
| FIRST_VALUE | Sql.Ext.FirstValue() |
|-------------|----------------------|
```

> **Note** There is no limitation in window functions usage. `LINQ To DB` will create `SQL` and run query, if function is not supported or some part of function is limited in particular `Database` - error will be thrown on database side.

Comment: hey... I have tried this but I am getting System.NotSupportedException... Any help will be appriciated

Comment: Check if your `SQL` provider is supported. Try to simplify your query until it works and then add details gradually to detect what clause or operation causes the error. In general, you should experiment with `window-functions`, there are a lot of subtle details.